# How to generate T-SQL script with SMO

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, smo

I have a SQL Server database with some tables which each have a primary key and a few foreign key constraints.

I want to backup of database tables into a `.sql` file, so that I could restore the database as is some time later.

I tried couple of `ScriptOptions` combinations but I am not getting desired result.

Problem is that `CREATE` statement for tables is not showing up in their dependency order. If Table A has the foreign key of Table B, then in my script the `CREATE` statement for Table A is listed first. By doing this I can not restore the database.

I tried using `ScriptOptions.WithDependencies = true`. But then `CREATE` statement for Table B is added twice, which I don't want.

I am using the approach of first taking the schema only dump then all the constraints and then the data dump in the same SQL file.

Here is my sample C# code snippet for this:

```
ServerConnection sc = new ServerConnection(args[0], args[1], args[2]);

Server myServer = new Server(sc);
myServer.SetDefaultInitFields(typeof(StoredProcedure), "IsSystemObject");
myServer.SetDefaultInitFields(typeof(UserDefinedFunction), "IsSystemObject");

Database db = default(Database);
db = myServer.Databases[args[3]];

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbConstraints = new StringBuilder();

Scripter dropScrp = default(Scripter);
dropScrp = new Scripter(myServer);
dropScrp.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;
dropScrp.Options.ScriptSchema = true;
dropScrp.Options.ScriptDrops = true;

Scripter createScrp = default(Scripter);
createScrp = new Scripter(myServer);
createScrp.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;
createScrp.Options.ScriptSchema = true;

Scripter constratintScrp = default(Scripter);
constratintScrp = new Scripter(myServer);
constratintScrp.Options.DriAllKeys = true;

foreach (Table tb in db.Tables)
{
    if (tb.IsSystemObject == false)
    {
        foreach (string s in dropScrp.EnumScript(new Urn[] { tb.Urn }))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(s);
        }

        foreach (string s in createScrp.EnumScript(new Urn[] { tb.Urn }))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(s);
        }

        foreach (string s in constratintScrp.EnumScript(new Urn[] { tb.Urn }))
        {
            sbConstraints.AppendLine(s);
        }
        sb.AppendLine("");
    }
}

sb.AppendLine(sbConstraints.ToString());
File.WriteAllText(args[4], sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem this way:

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sbConstraints = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sbData = new StringBuilder();

            Scripter dropScrp = default(Scripter);
            dropScrp = new Scripter(myServer);
            dropScrp.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;
            dropScrp.Options.ScriptSchema = true;
            dropScrp.Options.ScriptDrops = true;

            Scripter createScrp = default(Scripter);
            createScrp = new Scripter(myServer);
            createScrp.Options.ScriptSchema = true;
            createScrp.Options.NoCommandTerminator = false;
            createScrp.Options.ScriptBatchTerminator = true;
            createScrp.Options.DriPrimaryKey = true;
            createScrp.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;

            Scripter constratintScrp = default(Scripter);
            constratintScrp = new Scripter(myServer);
            constratintScrp.Options.Default = false;
            constratintScrp.Options.DriUniqueKeys = true;
            constratintScrp.Options.DriForeignKeys = true;
            constratintScrp.Options.DriPrimaryKey = false;

            Scripter dataScrp = default(Scripter);
            dataScrp = new Scripter(myServer);
            dataScrp.Options.ScriptData = true;
            dataScrp.Options.ScriptSchema = false;

            foreach (Table tb in db.Tables)
            {
                if (tb.IsSystemObject == false)
                {
                    foreach (string s in dropScrp.EnumScript(new Urn[] { tb.Urn }))
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(s);
                    }

                    foreach (string s in createScrp.EnumScript(new Urn[] { tb.Urn }))
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(s);
                    }

                    foreach (string s in constratintScrp.EnumScript(new Urn[] { tb.Urn }))
                    {
                        sbConstraints.AppendLine(s);
                    }

                    foreach (string s in dataScrp.EnumScript(new Urn[] { tb.Urn }))
                    {
                        sbData.AppendLine(s);
                    }

                    sb.AppendLine("");
                    sbConstraints.AppendLine("");
                    sbData.AppendLine("");
                }
            }

            sb.AppendLine(sbData.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine(sbConstraints.ToString());
```

This will generate the sql script in the following order.

1. For Every Table

   1. Drop statement with if exist check.
   2. Create statement with if not exist check. This will also include primary key constraint.
2. Insert data statements for every table.
3. Create constraints statement for every table (not primary key constraints).

   I have to first insert the data into table before applying constraints because i am not getting any way to insert the data in their dependency order. Which was my original problem also. So, i first inserted data and then applied constraints on the table.